# Insight for installing pip with sudo python3 get-pip.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

```
Last login: Sat Jan 16 16:54:40 on ttys001
ugland@Uglands-Air ~ % curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
...
ugland@Uglands-Air ~ % sudo python3 get-pip.py
Password:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/distutils_patch.py:25: UserWarning: Distutils was imported before Setuptools. This usage is discouraged and may exhibit undesirable behaviors or errors. Please use Setuptools' objects directly or at least import Setuptools first.
warnings.warn(
WARNING: The directory '/Users/Ugland/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
    Downloading pip-20.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
    |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 6.2 MB/s 
    Collecting wheel
Downloading wheel-0.36.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
   Attempting uninstall: pip
       Found existing installation: pip 20.2.3
       Uninstalling pip-20.2.3:
           Successfully uninstalled pip-20.2.3
Successfully installed pip-20.3.3 wheel-0.36.2
ugland@Uglands-Air ~ % python3 -m pip --version
pip 20.3.3 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
```

New to python as of this past month, and the textbook I'm following along with recommended to install pip via:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

Which, only after the fact, realized it was a mistake. I'm reading that installing pip in your home drive with elevated permissions can ruin your software - and I'm wondering, given that my the terminal said it deleted an earlier version of pip, can I just delete/remove/uninstall the root location of pip. And then how would I do that safely? Any help is appreciated, as I'm confused with all the technical details. Thinking a factory reset is my best option right now.

Comment: are you using the Anaconda distribution of Python or did you load it from python.org?

Comment: Downloaded from python.org, but I had downloaded the Anaconda distribution very recently.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your python installation comes with PIP, if I was you, I would simply run `pip install --user pip`

The `--user` flag causes PIP to install packages into a user-specific directory. You may see a warning when doing that, along the lines of:

> WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3.9, and pip3 are installed in
> '/Users/Ugland/Library/...' which is not on PATH.
>
> Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this
> warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

If you do see that warning, you should edit `~/.bash_profile` to add the following entry:

```sh
export PATH="/Users/Ugland/Library/...:$PATH"
```

**Note**: You need to replace the `/Users/Ugland/Library/...` with whatever path PIP showed you in the warnings. Also, mind the colon (`:`) between the path you are adding and `$PATH`.

After adding the entry to your `~/.bash_profile` file, you should be able to run `source ~/.bash_profile` to cause the newly installed libraries to be added to your path. In rare cases, you might need to launch a new terminal window or tab.

If you did *not* see the warning mentioned above, then PIP's directory was already part of your `$PATH`, so you should be good to go. For good measure, though, you may want to run `hash -r`, which tells bash that it should forget all full path locations it has remembered up until that point. (Without running `hash -r`, bash will sometimes resolve to old versions of executables.)

Finally, if you invoke `which pip`, you should see a path located somewhere in your home directory.

> ... can I just delete/remove/uninstall the root location of pip. And then how would I do that safely?

As for the question about deleting the version of pip installed at the system level, I would leave it be. Seems that it was already installed and you running `sudo python3 get-pip.py` might have updated it to a newer version. If you really wanted to, you could downgrade it, but it should not hurt anything to leave it at the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Anacionda distribution of python then you don't need pip. Use conda to install a package. First make a virtual environment by typing 'conda create -n yourenvname python=x.x anaconda' where x.x is the version of python you wish to use. Now activate you virtual environment by typing 'source activate yourenvname' You can load packages by typing 'conda install packagename'. You should now be able to run python.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I get the virtual environment comment, but I'm worried about leaving the pip within my home drive. A ton of people have voiced their concerns with the sudo method. "Using "sudo pip install" can and will overwrite python content provided by your OS vendor. When that happens, any vendor packages affected by this will not pass an "rpm --verify" and your packages will appear to be corrupted.

Do you want to use system-administration tools that your OS vendor has tested, or is it okay to use untested components you downloaded from the internet?"